# batch - error by compiling a C# project

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am trying to compile project "MyProjectName" from the windows command line.

this is the code:

```
PUSHD E:\
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:library Projects\MyProjectName /define:DEBUG /out:\Projects\MyProjectName\debug\MyProjectName.dll *.cs
```

I get the errors:

```
source file "Projects\MyProjectName" could not be found
source file "*.cs" could not be found
```

Comment: i don't think the csc compiler can compile all .cs with wild card.Rather you need to compile .proj file where the files are described.

Comment: My guess is that you just wanted `Projects\MyProjectName\*.cs` instead. But why not supply your project file to msbuild?

Comment: @npocmaka: No, csc absolutely *can* handle wildcards.

Comment: @npocmaka: if you run this in a *reasonable* shell, the shell substitutes the wildcard with a sequence of files. Wildcard handling is done by shells.

Comment: consider using the Developer Command Prompt instead. This will prepare the environment so you can just call csc from within the project direcory.

Comment: I change the source to  "Projects\MyProjectName\MyProjectName.csproj". now i only get one error:  "source file "*.cs" could not be found"

Comment: Where is the `*.cs` file located? how is it called? I think you cannot specify a wild-card like `*` here, I guess you need to provide a dedicated file; and I recommend to provide the full path...

Comment: it does expand wildcards. it can even search subdirectories with the /recurse switch. see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

When your current path is

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
```

Then the relative path specification

```
Projects\MyProjectName
```

would be expected as a subdirectory of the current path, which it might not be. specify an absolute (rooted) path for the project directory.

The PUSHD command seems to have no effect with just the drive letter - otherwise, the csc would complain like "source file E:\Projects... not found"

Working solution with repositioned /target switch and combined source argument:

```
csc.exe /out:\Projects\MyProjectName\debug\MyProjectName.dll /target:library Projects\MyProjectName\*.cs /define:DEBUG
```

Comment: Hot to solve it?  writing E:\Projects\MyProjectName  doesn't help.

Comment: I got this working with version 4.0.30319.
See last line of updated answer.

The changes were:
1) place the /target switch before the source path (compiler complained, that /target and /out must precede source)
2) combine the source path and the wildcard into one argument
3) the csc did not create the debug subdirectory. it failed, until I manually created it.

Comment: thanks. the compilation runs. the problem is that it doesn't find the resources that dont have a .cs suffix. I tried to change target to /target:library Projects\MyProjectName\*.*  , but then i get other errors. maybe becuase, part of those resources are in tested folders.

Comment: use the /resource argument to embed .NET resource files. for detailed syntax, see here: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c0tyye07.aspx)

Comment: use the /recurse switch to search for input files in nested folders.